# How to receive post request value from send using request in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the request package in Nodejs to send a post request to another Nodejs server:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://12.12.12.12:3230/',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: { 
            Num:1212,
            Cust:'TEST'

    },
    json: true
};

   request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);

console.log(body);
// Process the body and return the response.
// return res.send(body);
});
```

In my another Nodejs Server:

```
app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
   console.log(req.body.Num)
    console.log(`Someone sent a post request`)

})
```

My second Nodejs server, where I am listening for POST request displays the following in the console:

```
undefined
Someone sent a post request
```

How do I receive the value of the post request in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure to add **bodyParser** in your backend middleware, something like:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and require it on top like:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I forgot the line `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: oh hope the response was helpful, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the body to JSON.

```
body: JSON.stringify({ Num:1212, Cust:'TEST' }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use a body parsing middleware above all routes such as [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.json), ie:

`app.use(express.json())`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at bodyParser middleware in express

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser